# How to customise UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Tags: grails, spring-security

How to create custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in grails? I want to customize following method.

```
1. attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
2. successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult)
3. unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement your own class that extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` (or one of it's subclasses) and then replace the default authentication processing filter by defining a spring bean named `authenticationProcessingFilter` in `conf/spring/resources.groovy`.

Here's an example that uses an X509 certificate for authentication, rather than a username and password.

```
class AuthenticationProcessingFilter extends RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        X509Certificate[] clientCertificates = request.getAttribute('javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate')
        X509Certificate clientCertificate = clientCertificates ? clientCertificates[0] : null

        Authentication authentication = new X509Authentication(clientCertificate)
        authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication)
    }
}
```

### resources.groovy

```
authenticationProcessingFilter(AuthenticationProcessingFilter) {
    authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
    sessionAuthenticationStrategy = ref('sessionAuthenticationStrategy')
    authenticationSuccessHandler = ref('authenticationSuccessHandler')
    authenticationFailureHandler = ref('authenticationFailureHandler')
    rememberMeServices = ref('rememberMeServices')
    authenticationDetailsSource = ref('authenticationDetailsSource')
    filterProcessesUrl = conf.apf.filterProcessesUrl
    usernameParameter = conf.apf.usernameParameter
    passwordParameter = conf.apf.passwordParameter
    continueChainBeforeSuccessfulAuthentication = conf.apf.continueChainBeforeSuccessfulAuthentication
    allowSessionCreation = conf.apf.allowSessionCreation
    postOnly = conf.apf.postOnly
}
```

If you're overriding the `authenticationProcessingFilter` bean, it's quite likely you'll need to override the default `daoAuthenticationProvider` bean too.

The `authenticationProcessingFilter` bean is responsible for reading the authentication data (from the HTTP request, usually) creating an `Authentication` instance from it, and triggering the authentication process, but it's the `daoAuthenticationProvider` that actually performs the authentication.